# How to sum a sparse matrix rows in the first column, and zero the other colums, with the same dimensions of the original matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix B, I want to get the sparse matrix A from B by summation of all rows in the first column, then dividing the first column by '2', and making the other columns zero.

```
from numpy import array
from scipy import csr_matrix

row = array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
col = array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
data = array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

B = csr_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3) )

A = B.copy()

A = A.sum(axis=1)/2
# A shape becomes 1 x 3 instead of 3 x 3 here!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be approached in several ways.  Your's is fine.

```
In [275]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix 
     ...:  
     ...: row = np.array([0,0,1,2,2,2]) 
     ...: col = np.array([0,2,2,0,1,2]) 
     ...: data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6.])    # make float 
     ...:  
     ...: B = csr_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3) )                                              
In [276]: A = B.copy()                                                                                 
In [277]: A                                                                                            
Out[277]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The assignment works:

```
In [278]: A[:,0]  = A.sum(axis=1)/2                                                                    
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:126: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_arrayXarray(i, j, x)
In [279]: A[:,1:] = 0                                                                                  
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:126: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_arrayXarray(i, j, x)
In [280]: A                                                                                            
Out[280]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [283]: A.eliminate_zeros()                                                                          
In [284]: A                                                                                            
Out[284]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [285]: A.A                                                                                          
Out[285]: 
array([[1.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [1.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [7.5, 0. , 0. ]])
```

The efficiency warning is mainly intended to discourage iterative or repeated assignments.  I think that for one-time actions like this they can be ignored.

Or if we start with an all-zero `A`:

```
In [286]: A = csr_matrix(np.zeros(B.shape))   # may be better method                                                         
In [287]: A[:,0]  = B.sum(axis=1)/2                                                                    
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:126: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_arrayXarray(i, j, x)
In [288]: A                                                                                            
Out[288]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Alternatively that column sum matrix could be used to construct `A` directly, using the same style of inputs as used to define `B`:

```
In [289]: A1  = B.sum(axis=1)/2                                                                        
In [290]: A1                                                                                           
Out[290]: 
matrix([[1.5],
        [1.5],
        [7.5]])
In [296]: row = np.arange(3)                                                                           
In [297]: col = np.zeros(3,int)                                                                        
In [298]: data = A1.A1                                                                                 
In [299]: A = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3,3))                                              
In [301]: A                                                                                            
Out[301]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [302]: A.A                                                                                          
Out[302]: 
array([[1.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [1.5, 0. , 0. ],
       [7.5, 0. , 0. ]])
```

I don't know which approach is fastest.  Your `sparse.hstack` looks nice, though under the covers, `hstack` is building the `row,col,data` arrays from the `coo` formats, and making a new `coo_matrix`.  While it is reliable, it's not particularly streamlined.

Answer (score 0):

I demonstrate how to load a sparse array directly

```
row = np.array([0,0,1,2,2,2])
col = np.array([0,2,2,0,1,2])
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

B = csr_matrix( (data,(row,col)), shape=(3,3) )

sparseMatrix = csr_matrix((3, 3), 
                      dtype = np.int).toarray()

my_tuple=list(zip(row,col))
index=0
for item in my_tuple:
    sparseMatrix[item[0],item[1]]=data[index]
    index+=1


print(sparseMatrix.sum(axis=1)/2)
print((B.sum(axis=1)/2).flatten())
```

output:

```
[1.5 1.5 7.5]
[[1.5 1.5 7.5]]
```